# How would I modify this active record query to first check for an exact match?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  end
end
```

How would I modify this function so that it first checks if there is an exact match for the `search` parameter in the `name` field and, if there is an exact match, returns that match instead of the result of the `LIKE ?` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def self.search(search)
     if search
          results = find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "#{search}"])
          results = find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]) if results.empty?
     end
end
```

For complex searches I would suggest to use a seatrch engine like sphinx

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following, although it might potentially take two queries:

```
result = where("name = #{search}")
result.empty? ? where("name LIKE %#{search}%") : result
```